# Cast from long to int

Tags: data-type

How does arduino uno cast from **long** to **int**?

Does it truncate the bits? (Does it just delete the 16 most left bits?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it just blindly chops off the upper 16 bits.  That means that the sign can change between the two.

For instance, 123456789 gets truncated to -13035 and -123456789 truncates to 13035.

To see that in more detail, look at the binary.  123456789 in binary is:

```
0000 0111 0101 1011 1100 1101 0001 0101
```

Truncate that at 16 bits and you get:

```
1100 1101 0001 0101
```

And of course the high (sign) bit is set, so the value is negative.